# Error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I have this code:

```cs
var advertApiModel = _mapper.Map<AdvertModel>(model);

var jsonModel = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertApiModel);
var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri(
                   $"{_baseAddress}/create"),
                   new StringContent(jsonModel, Encoding.UTF8, 
                   "application/json"
               )).ConfigureAwait(false);
var createAdvertResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CreateAdvertResponse>().ConfigureAwait(false);
var advertResponse = _mapper.Map<AdvertResponse>(createAdvertResponse);
```

When I run this and trace it, it keeps getting the error `Invalid expression term 'string'` at var response and the terminal displays:

> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.ClientHandler[101]
>             Received HTTP response after 246.85940000000002ms - InternalServerError
>       System.Net.Http.HttpClient.IAdvertApiClient.ClientHandler: Information: Received HTTP response after 246.85940000000002ms - InternalServerError

Comment: Apparently the request you're sending leads to an error on the server. Without knowing the API and what it expects (and what exactly you are sending), I doubt there's anything to help you with.

Comment: _"Invalid expression term 'string'"_ - where does this show up?

Comment: @CodeCaster It shows when i hover over encoding. when it tries to create StringContent, it reads jsonModel but when i hover over "application/json" is gives that error and then everything breaks

Comment: Remove `new StringContent` and use `jsonModel` variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow Cosmin Mihalache.

I think using your variable jsonModel instead of the new StringContent may help you:

```
var response = await _client.PostAsync(new Uri(
                   $"{_baseAddress}/create"),
                   jsonModel
               )).ConfigureAwait(false);
```